# WOW.js : MutationObserver is not supported by your browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wow.js

[image]

This warning is showing in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the issue is still open. Maybe you can use this workaround:

```
var wow = new WOW({
    live: false
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/166

Answer (score 0):

It is not still working so far.
But you can copy the wow js code and adjust it a little bit.
The root cause is `this` context is WOW not the window.

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code as text in your answer, instead of pictures? The pictures are difficutlt to read. And providing code as text allows users to copy it more easily, among other benefits.